# SQL-->To compare the date field in the 2 tables

Tags: sql

We have two tables named A and B .These two tables contains one common field i.e `DOB`. In the Table A it is populating as `01/11/2011(MM/DD/YYYY)` and Table B it is populating as `11/01/2011(DD/MM/YYYY)` I need SQL query to compare this field in the both of the table and fetch this value.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Specify the data types of the columns.

Comment: What is the type of your columns?

Comment: And of course, please post the SQL you have attempted. You'll get kinder responses if you show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Dates, in relational databases, are stored in an internal format.  Hence, I must assume that your tables are storing a date as a string or number.  The first thing to do is to fix this problem.  Using native formats is advantageous -- that is why they exist.

If I assume strings, you can solve this problem using string manipulations.  Although the functions may differ among databases, the idea is the same:

```
from a join
     b
     on right(a.dob, 4) = right(b.dob, 4) and        -- compare years
        left(a.dob, 2) = substring(b.dob, 3, 2) and  -- compare months
        substring(a.dob, 3, 2) = left(b.dob, 2)      -- compare days
```

Because of all the functions, the SQL engine will not be able to take advantage of an index.  Go back to my first advice and store the dates as the appropriate `date` type for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
SELECT
    A.DOB,
    A.DateTimeField - B.DateTimeField Difference
FROM
    TableA A
JOIN
    TableB B ON A.DOB = B.DOB
```